# is synchronization needed with multiprocessor in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessor

when using a code like this

```
def execute_run(list_out): 
   ... do something 

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(6)
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
            pool.submit(myfunc, list_out)
pool.join()
```

assuming the threads modify list_out, do they do that in a synchronous manner?

Comment: Is that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` library?  If so, I don't think it has a `join` method.  Did you mean `shutdown`?

Comment: What's going on in `execute_run`? Does result depend on previous execution?

Comment: I basically need a place where each thread can put the results, possibly a list, in a way that there are no race conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is calculate something in multiprocessing way, it's better do not share state.
I propose you to use simple `map` from [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) if it's possible:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

input_list = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        input_list.append((i, j))

p = Pool()
result_list = p.map(do_something, input_list)
```

`map` works like for-loop:

```
def naive_map(input_list, do_something):
   result = []
   for i in input_list:
     result.append(do_something(i))
   return result
```

So, if you want to use function that is accepting several arguments, you can use lambda function for unpacking tuple.

```
  >> def your_function(v1, v2):
  >>        return v1+v2
  >> f = lambda (x,y): your_function(x, y)
  >> map(f, [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
       [3, 7, 11]
```

Comment: this way they would modify input_list in a synchronized manner right?

Comment: @Bobo, this way they would **not** modify input_list at all. They would read it only. So, if you can prepare your data to processing in such way, you should do it.

Comment: I need them to be able to write the results somewhere when they are done. How would I go about it?

Comment: @Bobo, I had added some extra explanation. You should return some value in `do_something` function. And for each element in `input_list` you will receive return value in `result_list`.

Comment: @Bobo, and yes. `result_list` will be consistent without race conditions.

Comment: my function uses multiple arguments. when passing either a tuple or a list with input_list.append(...) it complains that multiple arguments are needed. is there a nice way to fix it, without changing the function signature?

Comment: @Bobo, you can use `lambda` function. `lambda (p1, p2): your_function(p1, p2)`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that each process receives a copy of the list, and so won't see changes made by the other processes.

To achieve what you want you will have to use a [`Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to create a list proxy. Note that the manager proxy classes do not know when a member is mutated. For example, if an element of a list proxy is mutated somehow, the list proxy has no way of knowing this. You must reassign the member to flush the changes. An example from the documentation:

```
# create a list proxy and append a mutable object (a dictionary)
lproxy = manager.list()
lproxy.append({})
# now mutate the dictionary
d = lproxy[0]
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2
# at this point, the changes to d are not yet synced, but by
# reassigning the dictionary, the proxy is notified of the change
lproxy[0] = d
```

Comment: The OP is using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, not a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.  So each thread is modifying the same list.

Comment: do you have a pointer to an example? I need to do something like the code I posted above, where each thread modifies the same list provided as argument. thank you

Comment: I think you could rephrase this to be a little more clear. I think that the way it's currently phrased, it gives the impression that changes such as appending to or popping from a managed list will not be propagated. It would be good to specify that the lack of propagation only applies to mutable items.

Comment: I missed that you were using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You will not gain any performance benefit as python cannot run separate threads on separate cores at the same time. This is because the interpreter itself is not thread-safe. However, threads share the same memory and do not need a manager -- you will still need a mutex/lock to protect access to shared variables. The documentation contains plenty of examples of how to use a manager,

Answer (score 2):

`multiprocessing` thread pools are just threads and don't have any magic to generally synchronize shared objects. You need to protect shared objects with a lock.

Comment: Or better yet, refactor your code so that you do not share any objects (except in a read-only fashion) and instead collate output objects in the main thread, after the other threads have run.